# WebSocket connection failed (Server-side blazor)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a .NET 5 Core app (Server side blazor) deployed to my IIS and I get a websocket connection error. The request remains in status "pending". Is there a way to track down what causes the error?

[image]

Comment: Make sure WebSockets is installed, it's not by default.

Comment: It was an issue with my VPN connection. When at home, I had this error but as soon as i went back to the office and started the app, that error did not pop up.